# Why Altium Designer crashes at the beginning of the simulation and doesn't show me the line of the transient simulation after 350ps?

Tags: transistors, altium

When I started designing my circuit it worked perfectly when I simulate it, but now after it began to be a complicated circuit I can't simulate it any more. Even if I attach the probe to a SIN voltage source it won't show me the sine wave. Instead I'll see a flat line at the point's voltage without any sine signal and the line would continue until it reaches 350ps or 25ns and stops.

Comment: I don't ever recall Altium crashing from a simulation, but I'm afraid that's not something we can help with; report it to them and hopefully they can fix the bug.  Though I don't see how you'd get to a view with times if it's crashed?

Comment: Thank you but is it because of my weak cpu in my laptop I'm using intel core i5 3317u is it a bad cpu to use for altium designer and can it be the reason to my problem because it sometimes starts the simulation and then stops after 2 minutes without any progress

Comment: Are you sure "crash" is the right word? Typically when Altium crashes either there's a "Information..." box, or it disappears outright (with a Windows "your application has crashed" dialog). It sounds more like you just have an unstable model. Is there anything in the Messages panel, perhaps?

Comment: It's not uncommon to have a simulation not complete successfully. Sounds like you need to fix something in your circuit or adjust the simulation parameters. We don't know what kind of components you are trying to simulate- for example whether the voltages and currents would be expected to change much in some picoseconds or nanoseconds.

Comment: Yes the message panel shows information the simulation start and 9 warnings that no dc path to the capacitors I'll connect them later and a fatal error "internal Error: can't allocate 808bytes" which i recently read and I didn't understand it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to make an amplifier from transistors and this error showed up when I've added tow new voltage reference branch in order to bias some transistors but i noticed that when i change the value of the resistor to a specific value the simulation starts and draw a line with an amplification less than one while it has to be one since it's common collecter buffering branch any one has any idea because i really need to complete my first design

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all i found the solution it was my unstable design caused this problem and the error "time step is too small".